# Is there an efficient Goldreich-Levin algorithm that generalizes to agnostic PAC setting?

Tags: time-complexity, boolean-functions, fourier-analysis, sample-complexity

Goldreich Levin algorithm is an algorithm that based on some assumption (boundness on Fourier coefficients) outputs the indices for most significant Fourier coefficients of a boolean function, however a strong assumption for this algorithm to work is the uniform distribution over the input domain. Is there a distribution free generalization for the PAC agnostic setting when the distribution is unknown? Is it efficient in terms of sample and time complexity?