# Is it possible to estimate the positive outcomes of a boolean function using an optimized version of Goldreich-Levin?

Tags: boolean-functions, fourier-analysis, sample-complexity

Let $\mathcal{X} = \{-1,1\}^n$ and $h: \mathcal{X} \to \{-1,1\}$, h can be expanded in the basis of monomials for the uniform distribution, or also can have a distribution free expansion (Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization).

I have two questions:

- Goldreich-Levin algorithm is used to approximate large Fourier coefficients of a boolean function and is limited to the case of uniform distribution. Still, it seems it can be naturally generalized to the distribution-free setting while maintaining the polynomial time complexity. If true, how does the sample complexity change in the general distribution-free setting? I did the math but surprisingly it remains the same, I'm wondering if I missed something.
- Can we express the probability of getting positive outcomes: $\mathbb{P}[h(x)=1]$ in terms of Fourier coefficients? And is there a known relaxed version of Goldreich-Levin + Low degree algorithm for estimating $\mathbb{P}[h(x)=1]$?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  When you have two questions, you can ask them separately.  I recommend that you show your work.  I suggest you define precisely what you mean by 'the distribution-free setting' and what you have concluded the sample complexity is, and show your work.

Comment: For the second question -- look at $\hat{h}(\emptyset)$. By definition, it's $\mathbb{E}[h(x)] = 2\mathbb{P}\{h(x)=1\}-1$. (also -- didn't you already ask the first? https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/53502/is-there-an-efficient-goldreich-levin-algorithm-that-generalizes-to-agnostic-pac)

Comment: @D.W. I will write the results by today and edit the post, thank you for pointing out that.

Comment: @ClementC the first question is different from the post as here I'm concerned about to how the sample complexity changes with the distribution-free setting, which I did but seems to stay the same, I find that weird, if it's general why Goldreich-Levin is only used in the case of uniform distribution.